# Can I set class "property" based on other property?

Tags: java, class, variables

I want to set property of class based on this first switch. If vrsta (eng. type) is krug (circle) I want to have its diameter (r) as property of its type Figura (eng. Figure), if it is pravouganonik(eng. rectangle) I want to have its sides: a and b, and if it kvadrat(eng. square) I want to have its side value (str). How can I fix my switch, it gives me compile error. Illegal start of type on switch(vrsta){, it gives me  expected on same line, orphaned case on case "krug". Thank you so much!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Figura{
String boja,vrsta;
Double povr;

switch (vrsta){
    case "krug":
        Double r;
        break;
    case "pravougaonik":
        Double a,b;
        break;
    case "kvadrat":
        Double str;
        break;
}

Figura(String b, String v){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    boja=b;
    vrsta=v;
    switch (vrsta){
        case "krug":
            r=sc.nextDouble();
            povr=r*r*3.14;
            break;
        case "pravougaonik":
            a=sc.nextDouble();
            b=sc.nextDouble();
            povr=a*b;
            break;
        case "kvadrat":
            str=sc.nextDouble();
            povr=str*str;
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Figura f1=new Figura(sc.nextLine(),sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println(f1.povr);
}
}
```

Comment: That cant fix my problem, I want to, when I instance my Figura object to have property like f1.str for an example.

Comment: You can't do it the way you show it in your code. switch statements are evaluated during runtime, whereas class member variables have to be declared at compile time. After all, the compiler must create class bytecode which already has the appropriate fields, and since the compiled class does not know which instances will have what geometry type, this doesn't work.

Instead, as suggested by @Rajeev Singh, use inheritance to create object instances which match the desired geometry type at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `compile error. Illegal start of type on switch(vrsta)` is raised because it doesn't follow the convention for defining members. Instead, it should be wrapped inside a member function.

A member should be defined like this

```
class A {
    modifiers type name;
}
```

A simple solution for this problem is to use inheritance. Create a base class `Figure`, and create other child classes `Circle`, `Square`, `Rectangle` from it.

```
class Figure {
    // base class
}

class Circle extends Figure {
    double radius;
}

class Rectangle extends Figure {
    double length;
    double width;
}

class Square extends Figure {
    double side;
}
```

In main you can create the object of the Class that you need

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Figure f;
    int type = 1; // set type as required

    switch(type) {
        case 1:
            f = new Circle();
            break;
        case 2:
            f = new Rectangle();
            break;
        case 3:
            f = new Square();
            break;
        default:
            f = new Figure();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `class Square extends Rectangle`?

Comment: @jsheeran Yes, it can, the answer is to just resolve the problem and not about Inheritance so I skipped it, but is a better practice.

Comment: I agree for that, but then in main method I need to call Circle c=new Circle(); for an example, but I want it to use by Figure f1=new Figure();. Is it even possible? I made this program in Pascal language so I was thinking if it could be possible in Java.

Comment: yes, you can do `Figure f = new Circle();` as `Figure` is a parent to `Circle`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm sorry if I was asking stupid questions, I am still learning!